# Can someone explain this quicksort method?

Tags: java, quicksort

Can you guys please explain this quicksort method? I am trying to implement this code into my program, but the author left no explanation on what it does, or how it does it. Also note that I am in highschool so please try to keep it understandable.

What I DO know about this is that it quicksorts a 2-D array. I also know that it uses recursion to perform its quicksort. Unfortunately, thats it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public double[][] quicksort(double[][] array, int key, int down, int top) {
    double[][] a = new double[array.length][2];
    System.arraycopy(array,   0, a, 0, a.length);

    int i = down;
    int j = top;
    double x = a[(down + top) / 2][key];

    do {
      while (a[i][key] < x) {
        i++;
      }
      while (a[j][key] > x) {
        j--;
      }
      if (i <= j) {
        double[] temp = new double[a[i].length];

        for (int y = 0; y < a[i].length; y++) {
          temp[y] = a[i][y];
          a[i][y] = a[j][y];
          a[j][y] = temp[y];
        }
        i++;
        j--;
      }
    } while (i <= j);

    if (down < j) {
      a = quicksort(a, key, down, j);
    }

    if (i < top) {
      a = quicksort(a, key, i, top);
    }

    return a;
  }
}
```

Comment: Seriously: [Google.](https://www.google.com/search?q=quicksort)

Comment: Do you know how quicksort, in general, works?

Comment: This is a very good chance to work on your code debugging skills. See what it does, print out some of the variables at different places, step through it and add your own comments as needed. Doing so will make you a stronger programmer.

Comment: @Serdalis, kind of, but there isn't any debugging to be done here since there aren't any bugs :) I'd say this is a code reading.

Comment: @PaulDraper To read one must first debug. - Confucius.

Comment: To debug one must first read. - Paul. I didn't run the code but I understood it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things to know:

- `array` is an array of key-value pairs, and it is being sorted by the keys.
- This quicksort returns a copy of the original array, instead of changing the existing one in place.

See comments:

```
public double[][] quicksort(double[][] array, int key, int down, int top) {
    //create copy of array (the author wanted to return a new one)
    double[][] a = new double[array.length][2];
    System.arraycopy(array,   0, a, 0, a.length);

    int i = down; //lower limit
    int j = top;  //upper limit
    double x = a[(down + top) / 2][key]; //the pivot

    do {
      while (a[i][key] < x) { //skip over smaller elements in beginning
        i++;
      }
      while (a[j][key] > x) { //skip over larger elements in end
        j--;
      }

      //now do some partitioning
      if (i <= j) {
        //create temporary array, for swapping elements
        double[] temp = new double[a[i].length];

        for (int y = 0; y < a[i].length; y++) {
          temp[y] = a[i][y];
          a[i][y] = a[j][y];
          a[j][y] = temp[y];
        }
        i++;
        j--;
      }
    } while (i <= j);

    //if there is a non-empty lower partition, sort that
    if (down < j) {
      a = quicksort(a, key, down, j);
    }

    //if there is a non-empty upper partition, sort that
    if (i < top) {
      a = quicksort(a, key, i, top);
    }

    //return the result
    return a;
  }
}
```

Comment: is System.arraycopy necessary for this quicksort to work, or can i delete it and replace 'a' with 'array' ?